# Exposed Views 2 filter for path alias

Tags: 7, path-aliases, views

I am surprised that I am not able to find an existing Views 2 filter for aliases (paths). Seems to be such a basic property to filter results by.

I know Views can filter by argument but I need it as an exposed filter.

Does anybody know of an existing module that does it -- or at least a snippet of code that would build such a filter?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22989/changing-url-of-exposed-filter/23061#23061

Answer (score 1):

[Views Path Filter](https://drupal.org/sandbox/bobodrone/1112406) might be what you're looking for. It lets you filter nodes by paths in a views filter. I don't know how well it works with exposed filters though.

Answer (score 0):

[Pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) has a filter it uses with its admin page @ /admin/config/search/path. You might be able to repurpose its code with a custom views filter.