# Clean URL in Exposed Filters in Drupal 7

Tags: views, uri, backups

How can i get a clean URL in my Exposed Filter and Contextual Filters. I want to create a archive were users can sort the nodes by its posted Date. I used contextual filter to achive this and its working fine when i pass the value in URL like.

"www.example.com/archive/10/09/2013".

But when i use a exposed filter and submit the value the URL became like this

"www.example.com/archive/archive?date_filter%5Bvalue%5D%5Byear%5D=2013&date_filter%5Bvalue%5D%5Bmonth%5D=9&date_filter%5Bvalue%5D%5Bday%5D=10"  and it returns a empty page.

How can i pass a clean value in Exposed Filter and make it work properly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at [Changing url of exposed filter](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22989/changing-url-of-exposed-filter)

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to split this off into two different views displays, one for the clean URL with contextual filters and one using the exposed filters.

The only other way I can think of is making the contextual filters optional, but that may not be possible.