# Where is views exposed form's submit handler located?

Tags: views

When views exposed form is submitted without ajax it redirects to somepage like http://example.com/reports?taxonomy=tid&date=27%20F6%20f2005 etc.

I am curious to know ,in views module,inc file where it's submit handler is located,where is ajax callback?

I tried for some hours but no luck.

I know about hooks like form alter but that's not a concern.

I have no specific requirements,just for drupal learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of its functions are handled in programmatic way. You can look all functions are declared in `theme.inc` file located at `module/views/theme/theme.inc` location. Its hard to understand that core functions. But if you want to play with these functions then you will have to use the [hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7) .

**NOTE:** Never try to change any core file.

Comment: No,I don want to hack ,just for knowledge:)

Answer (score 0):

You can hook in to the form and see submit handlers and which form elements have ajax callbacks by debugging the form.

`kpr()` is a function available when you have installed the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module.

```
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {       
  kpr($form);      
}
```

You will need to put the function above in a custom module.

Comment: How can I make that url user friendly after submitting the exposed form inside alter hook you suggested?

Comment: See this answer http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22989/changing-url-of-exposed-filter