# Change Views BETWEEN min/max filter to a cleaner URL format?

Tags: views, 8

Is there an easy way to change the default exposed BETWEEN filter to work with:

`price=1000-2000`

Instead of:

`price[min]=1000&price[max]=2000`?

Would it be reasonable to create my own Numeric filter or am I looking at a lot of modification?

Comment: I could swear there was a similar question for D8 a while ago, but I can only find this one for D7 https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22989/changing-url-of-exposed-filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create redirects with rewrite rules outside of Drupal, in your server configuration. You can add them in Drupal settings too.

There is a module that did this for Views in D7 but it needs more help with D8, help if you can:

[Query Parameters To URL](https://www.drupal.org/project/query_parameters_to_url)